# How to add text in form of list in UITextView when tap UIButton (Swift 4)?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios12, swift4.2, xcode10.1

I come to you because I need your help for Swift 4.

So, this is why I need you: I searched to add text into UITextView when I tap on an UIButton. That’s OK, I have found the solution.

```
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {

    myTextView.text = "Button 1"
}
```

But, now, I search how to add this same text in my TextView with an list, in this case add the text many times I need and it adds in the form of a list each time in a new line.

I have four buttons and I want add text in TextView when I tap in an button but with an list.
Example:
Button 1
Button 2
Button 3
Button 4
Button 1
Button 2
Button 3
Button 4
Etc.

If you have the solution of course... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let btStr = ""

myTextView.text =  "\(myTextView.text!)\n\(btStr)"
```

Comment: Sh_Khan Thank you! I test this!

Comment: 'code'@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let button1 = "Button 1"
        myTextView.text = "\(myTextView.text!)\n\(button1)"
    }
    
    @IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let button2 = "Button 2"
        myTextView.text = "\(myTextView.text!)\n\(button2)"
    }'code"